# fiducial mapping with ROS Kinetic Kame

Tags: mapping, ros, aruco

I am currently working with the ROS package [fiducial_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/fiducial_slam). I get the positions and orientations of the [ArUco markers](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html).

Is it possible to create a map, so that I can still see the markers in [rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz), when I move my camera away? I am looking for something like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=MlOy9qt_K4Y

Unfortunately the [aruco_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/aruco_mapping) package doesn't work on Kinetic Kame any more. Does it work with fiducial_slam? What parameters do I have to choose?

[picture1:camera detects all markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuD1z.png)

[picture2: marker are not in camera view anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNH1h.png)

[picture3: marker are not the same like the transformed based](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AdqN.png)

Launch file:

```
<launch>

<node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node">
<remap from="usb_cam/image_raw" to="camera"/> 
</node>
<node name="aruco" pkg="aruco_detect" type="aruco_detect">
<param name="dictionary" type="int" value="0"/>
<param name="fiducial_len" type="double" value="0.36"/>

</node>


<arg name="publish_tf" default="true"/>
<arg name="do_pose_estimation" default="false"/>


<node type="fiducial_slam" pkg="fiducial_slam" output="screen"
name="fiducial_slam">
<param name="map_file" value="$(env HOME)/.ros/slam/map.txt" />
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="future_date_transforms" value="0.0" />
<param name="publish_6dof_pose" value="false" />
<param name="do_pose_estimation" value="$(arg do_pose_estimation)"/>
<param name="fiducial_len" value="0.36"/>   <!-- 0.36m -->
<remap from="/camera_info" to="/camera/camera_info"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the node if fully functioning add `fiducials (visualization_msgs/Marker)` to the rviz

Comment: I can see a green square then, but the marker axis still disappear, when I move my camera.

Comment: Upload A screenshot if u can

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot. I am not sure, if I said it clearly, I want to stick the markers to the map, when the camera can't see the markers anymore. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: In Your Rviz Add Visualization Marker and set It To The `fiducials` Topic This Way U Get The Shape And Correct Pose Of The Tag Instead Of The Transform Based On Your World Frame

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I had a few weeks off, so I just started working on this issue again. I added another screenshot, how do I have to choose the parameters so that transformed based fid12, fid 15.. match with the red markers?

Comment: What U have added i  your rviz config is TF,Grid,2 Image . In order to see the contents of the detected markers (like pose, model, etc ) add the visualization_marker type in your rviz and set it's topic to `fiducials` using add botton on left side of the rviz